# How to access elements of list in accessor

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

I have two data models, `company` and `contact_person`. They are linked in a m2m variant:

models.py:

```
class ContactPerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('first name', max_length=120)   

    @property
    def contact_name(self):
        return [self.name, self.id]

   
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('company name', max_length=120)
    contact_persons = models.ManyToManyField(ContactPerson, blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def contacts(self):
        persons = []
        for c in self.contact_persons.all():
            persons.append({"name": c.contact_name[0], "id": c.contact_name[1]})
        return persons
```

tables.py:

```
class CustomerTable(django_tables2.Table):

    name = django_tables2.LinkColumn("customer-detail",
                                     args=[django_tables2.A("pk")])

    contacts = django_tables2.LinkColumn("contact-detail", 
                                         args="contacts__id",
                                         accessor="contacts__name", 
                                         verbose_name="contacts")

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        sequence = ("name", "contacts")
```

What I want is that every name is linked to it's contact detail, but I am addressing the content of the accessor wrong, therefore get an empty table row.
Is my method with creating a list wrong `[{"name": "Bart", "id": 1}, {"name": "Rita", "id": 7},]` or did I just read the docs wrong on how to access that list?

views.py:

```
class CustomerListView(SingleTableView):
    model = Customer
    context_object_name = 'customer'
    table_class = CustomerTable
    template_name = "customerlist.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(CustomerListView, self).get_queryset()
        return list(qs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out after some help I was on the wrong track with using `LinkColumn`. I solved it with using a `TemplateColumn` and I wanted to share my approach - please feel free to comment or criticize:

models.py:

```
class ContactPerson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)   

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('company name', max_length=120)
    contact_persons = models.ManyToManyField(ContactPerson, blank=True)
```

tables.py:

```
class CustomerTable(django_tables2.Table):

    TEMPLATE = '''
                  {% for contact in record.contact_persons.all %}
                    <a href="{% url "contact-detail" contact.pk %}">{{ contact.name }}</a><br/ > 
                  {% endfor %}
               '''

    contacts = django_tables2.TemplateColumn(empty_values=(),
                                       orderable=False,
                                       template_code=TEMPLATE)

    name = django_tables2.LinkColumn("customer-detail",
                                     args=[django_tables2.A("pk")])
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        sequence = ("name", "contacts")
```